# FreeType vs FreeType2

Tags: freetype, freetype2

What is the difference. Apparently  there are two web pages. The whole FreeType project is lacking proper clear information. Which is the latest?

FreeType
http://www.freetype.org/

FreeType2
http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/

Answer (score 2):

From [HERE](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/index.html)

> Please note that ‘FreeType’ is also called ‘FreeType 2’, to distinguish it from the old, deprecated ‘FreeType 1’ library, a predecessor no longer maintained and supported.

As you can notice, even menu links goes to FreeType2 page. So it's same product.

Comment: It does not state "FreeType 1" anywhere on that site, only "FreeType" and sometimes "FreeType2". Ok so the green one is the latest?

Comment: @KarlMorrison Blue is same as green. And green is newset